# How to insert arbitrary unicode characters in kde keyboard shorctuts (send keyboard input)?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, unicode

My goal is to bind the shrug emoji ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ to a key combination such as "Super+Maj+S", such that whenever I type those three keys together that sequence of characters is sent to whatever window is currently accepting keyboard input.

In KDE I do this via System Settings > Common Appearance and Behavior > Shorcuts and gestures > Custom Shortcuts

[image]

[The documentation says](https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kde-workspace/kcontrol/khotkeys/shortcuts.html#shortcuts-action-keyboard) to input the characters separated by a colon (:), but it says nothing about non ascii characters. When I tried that, only the ascii characters got printed, so instead of getting the desired result of `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`, I only get `__()_:`

Any idea on how to fix this ? is there a specific method of supplying unicode characters ?

Comment: It might be complicated. You might get it working with xdotool (i didn't). See the "ADDITIONAL INFORMATION", paragraph 3, in this (new) bug report: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=427682   ; I fear that the physical keystroke collide with the unicode, because some component breaks the unicode into its components (control-character + ascii).

Answer (score 3):

There's a systemic bug there.
I have 2 workarounds, using xdotool

1. install xdotool (`apt install xdotool`).
2. Create a **custom shortcut** with the script as action (New > Global Shortcut > Command/URL; Trigger: (your key combo)

### Workaround #1 - sleep

Add a `sleep` command before calling xdotool:

```
sleep 0.6
xdotool type "¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"
```

### Woraround #2

Release the shortcut keys before calling xdotool:

```
xdotool keyup Super+n
xdotool type "¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"
```

### notes:

- in my case, the script can be called by multiple shortcut keys. So I call `xdotool keyup` multiple time, for each key-combo.
- use *double quotes*. Don't ask me why. Not required for a single key.
- Escape the single backslash, i.e.  `"¯\\_(ツ)_/¯"`
- The reason for the workarounds, is that the key combo is using the meta key. If the meta key is pressed **while** the unicode code is sent to the current app, then Plasma is sending garbage to the current app / to the window management. With a small delay, it doesn't happen.
- xdotool sends it to the currently active window by default.
- This is obviously a big, ugly and fragile hack, NOT a rock solid feature. YMMV.
- There are numerous KDE bugs around this feature, one of them is about reusing old shortcuts. If it doesn't work immediately, I recommend logout / restart.

Comment: I created the script, chmod +x the script, tried it from the command line (works), edited and enabled an old custom shortcut to run the script, but then nothing is typed in the active window. I wonder how does the output from xdotool gets captured and redirected to active window though as xdotool takes a `--window` argument that is not given in the script ? or does KDE takes care of that ?

Comment: xdotool sends it to the currently active window by default. This is obviously a big, ugly and fragile hack, NOT a rock solid feature. YMMV. There are numerous KDE bugs around this feature, one of them is about reusing old shortcuts. Did you try to logout / restart?  What are the shortcut keys you're using? What is the target program?

Comment: I will try and remove the shortcut and create a new one. The keys used are Meta+Shift+s. The target window is usually the browser, or slack, or emacs.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, `xdotool` doesn't work. For example, it doesn't work with REAPER. Another solution is to use `pynput` Python library. Install it with `pip`:

```bsh
$ pip install pynput
```

Then put this command in to action:

```bsh
python3 -c 'from pynput.keyboard import Controller; Controller().type("¯\\_(ツ)_/¯")'
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated link for Custom Global Shortcut (Send keyboard input):
https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/khotkeys/kcontrol/khotkeys/shortcuts.html

Weird rules for each character entry ... to get a macro key to spew my eMail address I had to set the "Action field" to (exactly)

`:m:a:r:k:c:a:p:e:l:l:a:shift+2:t:w:c:n:y:.:r:r:.:c:o:m:`

Image of Desktop Plasma with Global Shortcuts (Macro key:
[image: Image of Desktop Plasma with Global Shortcuts (Macro key)]